# Spring boot application slow performance

Tags: java, spring-boot, jmeter, hikaricp

I have a very basic Spring boot application, which exposes CRUD Rest APIs for a very simple entity. Running performance test using JMeter shows the very bad response time

`Product (id, name, description)`

**Constraints:** id PK AUTOINCREMENT

**Settings:**

- Number of Threads: 100
- Ramp-up period: 10 (seconds)
- Infinite loop
- Duration: 60 (seconds)

[image: Response Graph]
[image: Summary Report]

4 APIs exposed to perform the following functions

```
@Override
public Product findById(Integer id) {
    return repository.findById(id)
            .map(mapper::map)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new RecordNotFoundException(1, "Product not found"));
}

@Transactional
@Override
public Product create(Product Product) {
    ProductEntity entity = mapper.map(Product);
    
    repository.save(entity);

    return mapper.map(entity);
}

@Transactional
@Override
public Product update(Integer id, Product Product) {
    ProductEntity entity = repository.findById(id).orElseThrow();

    mapper.mapTo(entity, Product);

    repository.save(entity);

    return mapper.map(entity);
}

@Transactional
@Override
public void delete(Integer id) {    
    repository.deleteById(id);
}
```

I have tried to see the reason with visual VM. It seems repository functions are taking too much time. I assume its the database which is causing the issue.

**Connection pool settings:** As I have not set anything and assuming my applicaion is using HikariCP and default size is 100.

**Database:** For above results tried with MySQL (innodb engine) and have disabled autocommit.

**Spring Boot version:** 2.4.0

**System:** 16GB RAM, core i7

**Question:**

> Am I right its the connection pooling or database that is the bottleneck here and what will be the optimum value for pool size to reduce the response time?

> Why all APIs follow the same trend in the graph - together rise or drop?

**Update:**

1. Based on the suggestion hosted all of them on a separate machine (Cloud-based)
2. Profiled a bit - the repository is taking time (com.sun.proxy.$.methodName)

Comment: Is the JMeter test, Spring Boot and DB running on the same server (developer setup)? Are you using an SSD or HDD? In that case all the threads are competing against each other for CPU execution time. Every application should be executed on a different machine, like in production to get reliable measurements.

Comment: Here is some reading I hope will help: https://medium.com/kenshoos-engineering-blog/performance-degradation-in-production-whats-to-blame-8febfe707b9

Answer (score 0):

I can think of the following possible reasons:

1. The machine where your spring boot application runs lacks resources (CPU, RAM, etc.) - make sure to monitor them using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)
2. Use a profiler tool like [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/features/) or [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) to see where the application spends the most time
3. If you think that the problem is in the database:

- ensure that the database engine is properly set up i.e. follow [Optimization tips and tricks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimization.html)
- it might also be the case your queries are not efficient so inspect [query execution plans](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execution-plan-information.html), just adding relevant [indices](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) may speed up the things greatly

Comment: surely it's somewhere between repository and database (com.sun.proxy.$(Repository)Method taking all the time. I thought maybe tunning connection pool may help here

Answer (score 0):

You can do these to find the problem :

1- Use Gatling for your performance test, it uses the lower resource and doesn't impact your result.

2- Use an APM agent to monitor exactly what is the process that toke long, is database queries, or not([APM](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/current/setup-attach-cli.html))

3- use undertow instead of tomcat or other web applications